# How to open a document in another application from a view

Tags: xpages

I have modified the form's on web access, display xPage instead property and tried on runtime open selected document using xPage associated with the doucments form option, but this does not work. The current database is added at the start of the URL:

```
http://localhost/Requ%C3%AAtes852.nsf/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?databaseName=CN=Jocelyn%20Smith/OU=CSSS%20IUGS/OU=Reg05/O=SSSS!!iugs%5Cphysiosad.nsf&documentId=08FF9DFFD10070F585257A7F0053C282&action=editDocument
```

I must be missing something really basic. Does anyone have a work around? Thanks

Comment: not sure you have provided the whole scenario here. are you in a view opened from the other application? or are you using embedded views here?

Comment: In application A I have a simple view whose data source is a view from application B.  This works well.  But when I click on the link to open a document the URL contains applications A's address at the start.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by using a redirection page that reads the document id and database name from the URL parameters then redirects.  I'ld be interested in improving upon this solution though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
rendered="false"
viewState="nostate">
<xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript://Redirects to a page in another   application

var docid = param.documentId;  
var paramdbname = param.databaseName;
var hostname = context.getUrl().getHost();

//Get dbName without host
start = paramdbname.indexOf('!!');
dbName = paramdbname.slice(start+2);

var redirectstring = 'http://'+hostname+'/'+dbName+'/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId='+docid+'&action=editDocument';

try{

facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(redirectstring);
}
catch(err)
 {
//Handle errors here
 }}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
Redirects to a page in another application
```